# drupal 7 create a user profile view using user relationships fields

Tags: views, users

I would like to create a view using the **user relationships** module as well as the **profile2** module. I know you can use the concept of view relationships as they act like a join  other tables together. [views Relationships and argument?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/1534/views-relationships-and-argument) I am wondering the best way to assemble this with the profile fields and the relationships fields in a view. What would some best practice principle be. I also know I will need to use conceptual filters so that each user will have there own profile page. Should i extend the functionality of the user relationships browser view which has a path for each relationship or should i create my own view from scratch

Comment: I have figured this out. If anyone has a particular question then i will post an answer

Comment: I do have and I would really appreciate you posted how you solved this. Thank you.